# OSM tiles offline display using c++

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, c++

I have openstreetmap tiles for offline (png images), how can I display these images (tiles) on my application with zooming and rotation functionality as on openstreetmap.org using c++?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE .Please take the [tour] to learn how to ask as question. Your question as it stands is too broad for this format.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/47949/display-slippy-osm-tiles-offline-c

Comment: legitimate question

Comment: not a crosspost, this was first. and it's another website

Answer (score 2):

You could use CartoType (http://www.cartotype.com/index.html). The library supports map rendering, routing, turn by turn navigation, and geocoding.

For a comprehensive list of frameworks visit http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks. There are numerous other frameworks in the OSM environment depending on your needs.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. I need a osm map tiles viewer (as on openstreetmap.org) for my application on c++, but tiles (png images) should be loaded not via Internet, but from my local directory. Also I should add some graphics(polylines, rectangles etc.) to this map using C++. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can accomplish all of your requirements (incorporating offline tiles, drawing features) with cartotype. Visit the features page (http://www.cartotype.com/features.html) for more information or contact the developers (http://www.cartotype.com/contact.html). Your question "How can I do it" is to broad you should be a bit more concise.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question is mainly about zooming and rotating a png-image in C++. If this is correct the problem boils down to finding the proper image-processing library. I can suggest [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) for displaying, but for manipulation (including rotation) you may want to have a look at [openCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/?source=top3_dlp_t7) or at [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/).

Answer (score 0):

[Marble](https://marble.kde.org/) is open source, written in C++ and supports online and offline tile viewing. Apart from that there is a long list of [desktop software for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop) in the OSM wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you van also have a closer look at [libosmscout](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Libosmscout).
(found via [Frameworks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) in the OSM wiki)
Not sure myself whether it has tile display, but at least own offline vector map rendering in C++.